# How to simulate base+offset addressing and signed integer support in EMU8086?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, cpu-architecture, emulation

firstly i don't know anything about how EMU8086 works. Moreover my Assembly language skills are very very poor. I've to show offset+base addressing and signed integer support in EMU8086. I have been trying for days now but i dont seem to be getting anywhere. Could anyone help me out? A code with comments will do. Pleaseeeee help me i am desperate right now.

Comment: What have you tried? What progress have you made? What tutorials have you read?

Comment: Have you considered asking your instructor for help?

Comment: The basic thing they asked me to do was to simulate differences between 8080 and 8086 on EMU 8086. After research i found out that Signed int support and addressing is the main difference which i can implement perhaps. But next thing i knew i was lost! i just dont understand assembly. I asked the instructor, just didn't understand him when he started speaking "Assembly"

Comment: Understanding assembly is kind of a prerequisite for writing a CPU emulator. You can't really expect to be able to teach a CPU how to do something you don't know how to do yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorials right on the emu8086 website show how to do base-offset addressing:

http://www.emu8086.com/cx/asm_tutorial_02.html -

```
ORG 100H           ; make simple program 
MOV AX, 0B800h     ; AX = B800 
MOV DS, AX         ; DS = AX 
MOV CL, 'A'        ; CL = 'A' 
MOV CH, 1101_1111b ; CH = colour code 
MOV BX, 15Eh       ; BX = 015E 
MOV [BX], CX       ;  [DS:BX] = CX 
RET                ; exit
```

They load the base address 0xb800 into DS (data segment register), load up some values into the low and high portions of the CX register, load the offset address 0x015e into the BX register, and then write the values from CX into the base:offset address [DS:BX].

Comment: Thanks for explaining this code. Can you explain the signed integer support too? A small code just setting the SF on? That would do for me.Plus why do we write values from CX into DS:BX?